# Magento Cart Rule with Simple and Virtual products together

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, shopping-cart, rule

Cart rule = Free Shipping for carts with subtotal > $ 99.00

Scenario 01 - Cart with 3 simple products - OK, rule applied, free shipping.
Scenario 02 - Cart with 2 simple product and 1 virtual - FAIL, rule not applied.

Searching around I guess that this could be a Magento 1.7 bug.

Could you shed a light on this?

Comment: sorry you can't get the product type in promotion rules by default.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if there is some workaround for this scenario? I guess that it is a common need to have a basked with different produc types. Imagine a bookstore that sells books and ebooks, if the customer decides to get an ebook, he will have a penalty, no discount.

Answer (score 1):

So the problem with this is the code in the class `Mage_SalesRule_Model_Validator`

```
protected function _getAddress(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item_Abstract $item)
{
    if ($item instanceof Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Item) {
        $address = $item->getAddress();
    } elseif ($item->getQuote()->getItemVirtualQty() > 0) {
        $address = $item->getQuote()->getBillingAddress();
    } else {
        $address = $item->getQuote()->getShippingAddress();
    }
    return $address;
}
```

It decides which address to check depending on the item. If there is a downloadable item in the cart, it will take the billing address.
However, when a downloadable item is present together with a simple item, Magento will assign all the money values to the shipping address.

Thus, your rule will fail, because the subtotal is 0 at the billing address, but the downloadable item wants to check the billing address.

I think this is a bug in Magento and this method should be changed to reflect this issue.

An easy fix for this would be to rewrite the method to:

```
    protected function _getAddress(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item_Abstract $item)
    {
        $quote = $item->getQuote();
        if ($quote->isVirtual()) {
            return $quote->getBillingAddress();
        } else {
            return $quote->getShippingAddress();
        }
    }
```

Comment: seems 1.9.x has this fixed

Answer (score 0):

So far never found a work around, but the suggestion is to use either simple products in a separate `attribute set` Or separate `category`, then you can apply the rules, as attribute set and/or category can be used for applying rules.